# google chart executes before getting ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

i am newbie in jquery.i use google chart for my projects.i get a data from ajax but i can't able to use that value for loading graph.because the graph is calling before ajax completes the execution.
My Code is Below

```js
var a = [];

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'IssueStatistics',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            a.push(val);
        });
    }
});

google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work', a[0]],
        ['Eat', a[1]],
        ['Commute', a[2]],
        ['Watch TV', a[3]],
        ['Sleep', a[4]]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: call drawChart() in Ajax success method. comment out google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart). Or use setOnLoadCallback to post Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks jskunkie.I already tried this but at that time i am not comment the setOnLoadCallback.now i comment this line.it's working fine.thanks again

Comment: You should start the AJAX request from a callback from the google loader, as it is possible for the API to finish loading after the AJAX request finishes.